# Отсортировать рандомную матрицу змейкой и вторая задача -спиралью

Tags: c

На счёт программы в си...Как можно с помощью сортировки пузырьком или отбором или вставкой и через выделение памяти (malloc,calloc) отсортировать рандомную матрицу змейкой и вторая задача -спиралью???как дальше?

```
//Заполнить матрицу змейкой
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <windows.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{   
    setlocale (LC_ALL,"Russian");
    int *ms, n, i, j, k,b,m;
    float a;
    {
        printf ( "Vvedite razmer massiva " );                                  
        scanf ( "%d", &n );                                                    //размерность масства
        printf ( "Vvedite razmer massiva " );                                  
        scanf ( "%d", &m );   
        ms = ( int* ) malloc ( n*m*sizeof( int ) );                              //выделение памяти для массива

    }
    {
        srand ( time( NULL ) );                                                //функция заполнение массива случайными числами
        for ( i = 0; i < n; i ++ ) 
            for ( j = 0; j < m; j ++ ) 
        *(ms + i*m+j)= rand() % 100-100;                                         //диапазон чисел
    }

       {
        for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)      //сортировка пузырьком
       for (j = 0; j < m-1; j++)
        {for (j=n-1;j>i;j--)
        {for (j=m-1;j>i;j--)
        if(*(ms+j)<*(ms+j-1))
                {k = *(ms+j);
                *(ms+j)=*(ms+j-1);
                *(ms+j+1) = *(ms+j);
                *(ms+j-1) = k;
                } 
        }
        }
```

Comment: Ужас. Я не в силах понять, что это. Увы мне. Но я бы не стал хитрить, а сделал функцию (inline), которая бы отражала индексы одномерного массива на индексы матрицы. А сортировку уже после этого можно брать из учебника.

Answer (score 1):

не хочу приводить код, но алгоритм такой:

змейка:

1. создаём массив N х M и заполняем
       его.
2. сортируем любым способом
3. создаём новый массив N х M
4. делаем три цикла внешний и два
       внутренних, внешний проходит матрицу
       **сверху вниз**, а внутренние **слева на право** или **справа на лево** оба внутренних цикла
       заполняют новый массив значениями из
       старого
5. внутри внешнего цикла узнаём какая
       сейчас строка: чётная или нечётная в
       зависимости от этого вызываем нужный
       внутренний цикл.

спиралью:

1. создаём массив N х M и заполняем его.
2. сортируем любым способом
3. создаём новый массив N х M
4. создаём 4 переменные которые будут
       ограничивать уже заполненную часть
       матрицы
5. создаём 4 функции которые будут
       заполнять новый массив значениями из
       старого, но при этом будут учитывать
       ограничение из пункта 4 (заполнение **слева на право**, **справа на лево**, **сверху вниз**, **снизу вверх**)
6. делаем цикл который вызывает 4-и
       функции в нужном порядке

Answer (score 0):

[@ProkletyiPirat](/users/8821/prokletyipirat) страсти-то какие. Вот змейка (если я правильно понял, что это такое):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
enum {N=10, M=10};
int *ind(int ii, int n, int **matr) {
    int *iP = matr[ii / n];
    int j = ii % n;
    j = (ii/n) & 1 ? n - j - 1 : j;
    return iP + j;
}

int main() {
    int **matr = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * M);
    int i, j, flag = 1;
    for(i = 0; i < M; i++) matr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * N);

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            matr[i][j] = rand() % 1000000;
            printf("%6d ", matr[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    while(flag) {
        flag = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < M*N-1; i++) {
            int *i1 = ind(i, N, matr);
            int *i2 = ind(i+1, N, matr);
            if(*i1 > *i2) {
                flag = 1;
                int k = *i2;
                *i2 = *i1;
                *i1 = k;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("---------------------\n");
    for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < N; j++) printf("%6d ", matr[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    for(i = 0; i < M; i++) free(matr[i]);
    free(matr);
    return 0;
}
```

результаты:

```
289383 930886 692777 636915 747793 238335 885386 760492 516649 641421 
202362 490027 368690 520059 897763 513926 180540 383426  89172 455736 
  5211 595368 702567 956429 465782  21530 722862 665123 174067 703135 
513929 979802 634022 723058 133069 898167 961393  18456 175011 478042 
176229 377373 484421 544919 413784 898537 575198 594324 798315 664370 
566413 803526 776091 268980 759956 241873 806862 999170 906996 497281 
702305 420925 477084 336327 660336 126505 750846 621729 661313 925857 
616124 353895 819582 100545 898814 233367 515434 990364 344043 313750 
171087 426808 117276 947178 695788 393584 705403 502651 392754 612399 
999932  95060 549676 993368 947739 210012 636226 698586 348094 297539 
---------------------
  5211  18456  21530  89172  95060 100545 117276 126505 133069 171087  ----->
268980 241873 238335 233367 210012 202362 180540 176229 175011 174067  <-----
289383 297539 313750 336327 344043 348094 353895 368690 377373 383426  ----->
484421 478042 477084 465782 455736 426808 420925 413784 393584 392754  <-----
490027 497281 502651 513926 513929 515434 516649 520059 544919 549676  ----->
636915 636226 634022 621729 616124 612399 595368 594324 575198 566413  <-----
641421 660336 661313 664370 665123 692777 695788 698586 702305 702567  ----->
798315 776091 760492 759956 750846 747793 723058 722862 705403 703135  <-----
803526 806862 819582 885386 897763 898167 898537 898814 906996 925857  ----->
999932 999170 993368 990364 979802 961393 956429 947739 947178 930886  <-----
```

Comment: @alexlz я считаю вредным давать уже готовое решение для учебных задач, особенно тем кто только учится и\или тем кто только появился на хешкоде

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat пожалуй, что да. Только Ваш метод решения мне показался страшноватым, и я решил проиллюстрировать свой комментарий. Надеюсь, что ТС не будет копировать данный код ;)